# Apache Airflow not running command or sending output of command properly?

Tags: airflow

I'm running Apache airflow and whenever I run an aws command, there is no output being displayed.  The command works on the bash shell of the worker.  Right now the job will just hang waiting.  Is there something I have to do to send data to the airflow to tell it that the command has completed?

#### Logs

```
[2019-10-07 15:48:13,098] {bash_operator.py:91} INFO - Exporting the following env vars:
    AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_ID=lambda_async
    AIRFLOW_CTX_TASK_ID=aws_lambda
    AIRFLOW_CTX_EXECUTION_DATE=2019-10-07T15:48:01.310140+00:00
    AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_RUN_ID=manual__2019-10-07T15:48:01.310140+00:00

[2019-10-07 15:48:13,099] {bash_operator.py:105} INFO - Temporary script location: /tmp/airflowtmpj4r2x2xg/aws_lambda2qu0f2vl

[2019-10-07 15:48:13,099] {bash_operator.py:115} INFO - Running command: aws lambda --region us-east-1 list-functions

[2019-10-07 15:48:13,103] {bash_operator.py:124} INFO - Output:
```

#### Code

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
import datetime

default_args = {
'owner': 'airflow',
'depends_on_past': False,
'start_date': datetime.datetime(2019, 7, 30),
'email': ['xxxxxxxxx'],
'email_on_failure': False,
'email_on_retry': False,
'retries': 1,
'retry_delay': datetime.timedelta(minutes=5),
}


dag = DAG('lambda_async', default_args=default_args, schedule_interval=datetime.timedelta(days=1))

t1_command = "aws lambda --region us-east-1 list-functions"

t1 = BashOperator(
    task_id='aws_lambda',
    bash_command=t1_command,
    dag=dag)

t1
```

Comment: is it just the `BashOperator` task getting stuck or each type of task (even `DummyOperator`) getting stuck?

Comment: There is a proxy in my env.  After a long timeout, i was able to see the issue.  I updated my proxy settings snd all worked